# Why do I have to use `[[1]]` with data.table everywhere?

Tags: r, list, data.table, categorical-data

After indexing DT column with a variable name, the data is returned as type `data.table data.frame`, and the column is not an accessible vector, I have to unlist it first. Am I doing everything as intended?
Consider this example:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a=seq(1.001, 10.999, length=100), b=factor(c(rep('a', 55), rep('b', 45))))
col.name <- 'a'
diff(DT[, col.name]) #column name not found error
diff(DT[, col.name, with=FALSE]) #null data table
diff(DT[, col.name, with=FALSE][[1]]) #works
```

The second example is what question is about.

Comment: Maybe try: `as.data.frame(DT)[, col.name]`

Comment: `DT[, 'a', with = FALSE]` returns a `data.table` with one column `'a'`, `DT$a` returns a vector - that's just how it works

Comment: Here is another way: `diff(DT[[col.name]])`

Comment: @inscaven, how do I use variable column name with $ operator?
[at]ismirsehregal, yes, this is the way and correct answer.

Comment: for those who dislike square brackets: `diff(getElement(DT, col.name))`

Comment: and btw. instead of `with = FALSE` you can use `DT[, ..col.name]`

Comment: @ivan866 though `$` is not intended to support variable names for subset (`[[` is) here are some ways: ```library(rlang); eval_tidy(expr(`$`(DT, !!col.name)))``` or `setnames(DT, old = col.name, new = "column_to_extract")$column_to_extract` if not suggest a straight-forward but not recommended solution with `eval(parse(text = paste0("DT$", col.name)))`

Answer (score 1):

You have many options to retrieve single columns. In my opinion, the most readable option, is using `.SD`, though not the fastest. It's also often desired that single column `data.table`s are not converted to vectors.

```r
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(a=seq(1.001, 10.999, length=100), b=factor(c(rep('a', 55), rep('b', 45))))

DT[ , get(col.name) ] # vector
DT[[ col.name ]] # vecotr
DT[ , col.name, with = FALSE ] # data.table
DT[ , .SD, .SDcols = col.name ] # data.table
```

Answer (score 0):

Two (straight-forward) ways to to get just the vector and not the data.table, given your inputs:

```r
DT[, get(col.name)]
DT[[col.name]] # as per comment by ismirsehregal
```

And some equally convoluted as `DT[, col.name, with=FALSE][[1]]`

```r
with(DT, eval(parse(text=col.name)))
DT[, ..col.name][[1]] # as per comment by ismirsehregal
```